# Database structure for property where price vary depending on month

Tags: mysql, database

First of all I would imagine this issue is a common problem for developers to run into, but I tried searching both google and the forums for a couple of hours, and the results I found didn't really fit how I would describe my issue. So I apologize in advance if the answer should be easy to find, I just don't think I know the right terminology for it. Now, on to my problem :)

I'm building a database for a website that rents out properties. I'm facing a problem with a certain requirement for the database:

- Each property should have a variable price, depending on when you want to rent it.

For instance, property A has a daily rate of 100$ in January, but in February it should be 200$.

I'm struggling with how I go about achieving this. The closest I've come to a solution is having a column in my 'Property' table called 'Pricing', that takes in a text string with json structure, something like this:

```
{
  January: {
    Daily: 100,
    Weekly: 500,
    Monthly: 1800
  },
  February: {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

However, I feel like this isn't the optimal solution, and I'm also concerned about how to solve specific dates. Let's say that between January 1st and January 14th, prices should be different - I'm not sure how to implement that with the above approach in an elegant way, and I feel like going down this path is the wrong approach to begin with, so any suggestions are welcome :)

Furthermore, it's also a requirement that prices change, if a user frequently visits a certain property, but I'm not sure if it would be a good idea to solve this on a database level, or if it's better handled in another application layer?

Again I apologize if this is common knowledge, I just haven't been able to find the answer I was looking for.

Any suggestions are welcome, solutions as well as sources to read / watch, I feel like I'm not confident in any of the approaches I can think of.

Thanks for your time reading,

Kind regards,

Jesper

Comment: I would probably just go with a table which records the daily rates, assuming the price could ever vary on a daily basis.  Then, to get the total cost for an arbitrary range of time, you can just aggregate.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So having a table with "propertyId", "date", "price", where there should be an entry for each date of the year, for each property?

Comment: It depends on how the price varies.  If you are absolutely certain that prices would change only very slowly, and you would never have to manually increase the price for a certain date (e.g. July 4th in the US), then you might be able to just store the first date of a given fixed price range.

Comment: @Tim The prices would mostly be done manually, for specific properties

Comment: E.g.: room_rate(room_id,start_date(mm-dd),rate)